# Как в телеграмм боте на питоне сделать проверку пользователя на нажатие кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть допустим некая клавиатура которая вызывается ответом на команду, что бы достать айди человека который ее вызвал

```
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Text', callback_data = 'item_1')
    btn_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Text', callback_data = 'item_2')
    и есть проверка нажатия на одну из кнопок
    if call.data == 'item_1':
        print ("Text")
```

и если она вызывается в чате, то любой человек нажавший на кнопку вызовет ее `callback_data`.

Как сделать проверку на то что бы нажать на кнопку мог только тот кто ее вызвал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, почитав апишку телеги на меня снизошло озарение, и для данной проверки нужно написать: `if call.data == 'название' and call.from.user.id == id который вам нужен`